# Windows box occasionally repeating key "a" endlessly

Tags: windows-7, usb, keyboard

I am using a USB Microsoft keyboard on my Windows box, running Windows 7 x64 Ultimate. Occasionally, key <kbd>A</kbd> is typed endlessly although keyboard is not touched (or other key is touched). I have tried another keyboard - same problem. I have found it to do it even with no keyboard attached at all (one time after wake up from sleep mode).

Unpluging and plugin again the USB keyboard is the workaround I use.

What could it be?

Comment: That is unlikely.  Especially since replugging the keyboard helps.

Comment: Perhaps unlikely. Perhaps not. Regards,

Comment: When you say "with no keyboard" you mean with "no external keyboard" o "no keyboard at all"?. I mean, is your computer a laptop?

Comment: No, it's not virus. Nonetheless do you know of any recent virus with this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what caused me this problem:

An old connected **joystick** (not used for months) with custom configuration for various programs/games. The last selected configuration was <kbd>WASD</kbd> keys for directions. The joystick was covered with cables behind the monitor and one of the cables pushed it very slightly to the left, so key <kbd>A</kbd> was not typed always, but just with a very light air movement in the proper direction.

So, the solution was to disconnect the joystick.